# Geometry nodes Simulate project from view for UV map

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

Is there a way to simulate the project from view for uvs with geometry nodes? I know you cant project the uvs from the viewport point of view in geometry nodes (actually I wont be surprised if it is possible), but is there a way to sort of project the uvs of your mesh from one axis?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will do. but it's a match for the *UV Project* modifier given a single orthoghraphic projector:

[image]

It inverts the relative transform of the provided 'Projector' object, gives that transform to a copy of the modified mesh, and transfers the positions of the transformed  face-corners to a pre-existing UV map on the modified object.

[image]

It does *not* match projection from a camera, which must involve other jiggery-pokery, including a perspective transform. However, your view can be set to that of an orthographic projector-object by selecting it, and hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>